# AoCG2021 Day 20: Wonky license check

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem, parsing

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2018 Day 8](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/8).

---

The license file for an imaginary software system is defined as follows:

- The entire file is a sequence of non-negative integers.
- The entire file defines a *tree* of nodes.
- Each node in the tree has the following fields in the order:

  - Header, a single number indicating the number of child nodes.
  - Zero or more child nodes, as specified in the header.
  - Zero or more metadata entries (each being a single integer), as specified in the footer.
  - Footer, a single number indicating the number of metadata entries.

Hmm, does it really work? It should, because it is your job to validate the given license file!

An example of a valid license file:

```
2 0 10 11 12 3 1 0 99 1 2 1 1 1 2 3
A----------------------------------
  B----------- C-----------
                 D-----
```

A has two children (B, C) and three metadata entries. B has no children and three metadata entries. C has one child and one metadata entry, and so on. It is well-formed, so it is valid.

How about this?

```
2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

The root node has 2 children and 0 metadata. Then we need to divide `1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1` into two nodes. But:

- `1 0 0` is not a valid node: it has 1 child and 0 metadata, but single 0 is not a valid node.
- `1 0 0 1` is not valid either: it has 1 child and 1 metadata, but again we are left with single 0.
- `1 0 0 1 1` is valid (1 child, 1 metadata, `0 0` being the child), but the rest `0 0 1 1` is not a valid node.
- `1 0 0 1 1 0` is not a valid node because `0 0 1 1` isn't.
- The first child cannot be longer than that because the second must have 1 metadata.

Therefore, the second example is not a valid license file.

Given a license file as an array of non-negative integers, determine if it is valid. You can choose to

- output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
- use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Truthy:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 99, 99, 99, 3]
[2, 0, 10, 11, 12, 3, 1, 0, 99, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Falsy:

```
[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 2]
[3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Reports say that the guy who came with this format has since be fired. :-p

Comment: Suggest testcase: `[0, 0, 0, 0]` (cat of two valid license files).

Comment: But a valid license file may still be ambiguous. For example, both `[2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` -> `2{0(0 1 0 3);1{0(0)}(0)}(0)` and `[3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` -> `3{0(0);1{0(3 1)}(0);0(0)}(0)
` are valid, and then `[5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` is ambiguous. So, although we can do validation on it, it still does not work.

Comment: @tsh Depends on the definition of *work* :P But yeah, a fair warning: *Do not attempt this at home or at work.*

Comment: shorter ambiguous example: `3 0 ? 1 0 3 1 0 3 1 0 0 ? 1 0` can be `0 ? 1  --  0 3 1 0 3  --  1 0 0 ? 1` or `0 ? 1 0 3  --  1 0 3 1 0  --  0 ? 1`

Comment: shorter, still: `2 1 0 0 0 2 0 3 1 0 0 0 0` splits `1 0 0 0 -- 2 0 3 1 0 0 0` or `1 0 0 0 2 0 3 -- 1 0 0 0`  --  perhaps finding ambiguous codes may be a nice challenge for next Xmas?

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85</s> 80 bytes

```ruby
f=->l{a,*l,b=l;q=l.size;a==0?b==q:(1..q).any?{|x|f[l[0,x]]&&f[[a-1,*l[x,q],b]]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RDoIgFIbvewqvshowwCtz5IOwcwFbbm2sZeamqc9OCKPIjQMfP//hP89ej9Y2Al/MpNDJIC1M1QpDutv7WikhaK2FaM8HRkh7JOo@1tM8zI00kqIBYL9vpFSYuVY5oBaQBlgW@8icTFFGAXaemeOwouK4LH9VRJ17G1vLNTF3LdzhxdXniPudRfad/avLcoxxHj75hiRpLJmFJfpmrhAVYnkUizBUNKewcfL/1y0D2A8)

#### Let me explain:

The license is valid if:

- the first element is zero and the last element is the length of the list minus 2

or

- we can create 2 valid licenses by splitting the list in 2, removing the head from the first part and prepending it (minus 1) to the second part. A license in the format `a x x x x x x y y y y y y y` is valid if both `x x x x x x` and `a-1 y y y y y y y` are.

Comment: Nice observation

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 121 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,l=1:any(f(a[:i])*f(a[i:],l-1)for i in range(len(a)))if l>1else[[]==a,a>[]<(s:=a[:~a[-1]])and f(s,s.pop(0))][l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDLbsMgELz3KziyEam8oEqNVfIjhMNWMQkSxcjOJZf@uoNt5YEbRarEwjA7s7uQzqdjG9Vn6gandzkC/XzviZEIGmuKZ@44mdpbWI3A11aENYJrO@aZj6yjeGh4aCInAPCOhS02oW@MsVqToK2xX7yvda7xS2aN1gLFPXO8F/17ahOvAKwJdkidj6fczFSCVRbg7UZgJuZV0JnYbO6hiqScDDhGtmO@qnxM5CjOSE47XvFkv/vLTsu@uJwPnww895RFRs1jXR/0CJ7JZSlZ4nJkWVZVD/o/f6f@of14rX1dZrgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 49 bytes

```
f(0:x++[l])|length x==l=1
f(a:x++y)|a>0=f$a-f x:y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9Nw8CqQls7OidWsyYnNS@9JEOhwtY2x9aQK00jESRTqVmTaGdgm6aSqJumUGFV@T83MTNPwVYhTSHaSEfBQEfBEIQNgRjINQZSYEFLSzDLCEwawtjGsf8B)

A port of [@G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/9288).

This returns `1` if the license is valid, and nothing otherwise.

Though Curry has a Haskell-like syntax, its pattern matching is so powerful that this answer looks more similar to the [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240016/9288) than the [Haskell one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239996/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 81 bytes

```
f(a)=#a&&if(a[1],sum(i=2,#a,f(a[2..i])*f(concat(a[1]-1,a[i+1..#a]))),a[#a]+2==#a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3RCoMwDPyVoiB21mLqkw/uR0ofguAobK647WFf3yWtMjdomrvkchdw9e0lxDjXKMcSq8oTsuDU43Wr/WhUiYonRmvv5Gmup/sy4TNpWlBofQNal@iklMQINGYkIxkxhOu7RtGeRVj9QieiYFIIzpJKWNsp0TkCQD0/ZtSH4Vs9z0xaAxeJgWhPLQ1ZQ8ikH3acrpLbZglbEGz8EJh9sqfhQZ/TdtERHFTmd/OPnZPxAw)

A port of [@G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>94</s>  92 bytes

This is using [GB's great insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/58563).

Returns **0** or **1**.

```javascript
f=a=>a[a[n=a.length,0]+n-!!n]==n-2|a.some((_,i)=>f(a.slice(1,i))&&f([a[0]-1,...a.slice(i)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFBDsIgELz7Cr20EIEUevKAR1/grRJDKtUaBNNWExP/XrdtGluDCQuzszub2XDVT13nVXlvqPMn07aF1HKrM505qZk17txcSKLWjq5WTknpqHhrVvubQehISiy3BYLclrlBHHIcRQUCdaIoJ4yxsVZihXGbe1d7a5j1ZxRn@@rRXF4qxospD/KELBNo/6U50MMJFIHebL6RBlpEL@ZdwCgOaQpPT3YSQKK/@Yj7IbMp8cFlO23rkOuQqbBRHl6Oh7v/7zx4H/YQgXo6LDyOmIL/IjFv/MXdN34A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 67 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦θ⟧Ｆυ¿ι«≔⊟ιη¿η«≔§η⁰ζ¿‹ζ⁼§η±¹⁻Ｌη²⊞υι¿ζＦ…³Ｌη⊞υ⁺ι⟦✂η¹κ¹⁺⟦⊖ζ⟧✂ηκ⟧»»Ｐ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9BasMwEDzHr9ijBCrU9inkFGgOhSaY9mh8EM7GElHlxJJCccnb1ZWoQwQSq53ZmdleyakfpYmxCU6xIKC9dnxTnMYJWOCgT8A0h99itXVOD5Y144UaAhSRVglVGV3grX@3R/xhSsArsebEyrQPdI7NAnbXII175h1wkB5ZyYm/1zY44trBK1IWUHE6sGTTWQ6Nwxxs5pBzfko7IKsFPAafZhpDipr2@jK6x2RYCjjTy/@x9g37Cb/RejySZCfgwTxz3vHkeS/uRbbdB@P1ZdLWU@BNjG1b0aakli4Jl/StswU11utcVfktl7ruuvhyM38) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` if the licence is valid, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦θ⟧
```

Start by checking the whole licence as a list of one sublicence.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over the lists of sublicences.

```
¿ι«
```

If there are still sublicences to check:

```
≔⊟ιη
```

Remove one sublicence.

```
¿η«
```

If this sublicence is not trivially illegal, then:

```
≔§η⁰ζ
```

Get the number of its sublicences.

```
¿‹ζ⁼§η±¹⁻Ｌη²
```

If this is a valid licence with no sublicences, then...

```
⊞υι
```

... push the remaining sublicences to the list to scan.

```
¿ζ
```

Otherwise if this licence has sublicences, then:

```
Ｆ…³Ｌη
```

For each potential first sublicence:

```
⊞υ⁺ι⟦✂η¹κ¹⁺⟦⊖ζ⟧✂ηκ⟧
```

Append the first sublicence and the licence adjusted for the removal of the first sublicence to the list of licences to scan.

```
»»Ｐ¹
```

Otherwise, all sublicences validated and so this licence is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 378 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,N,C=[],P=[],Q=[...P,C]>=T extends[infer A,...infer R]?a<R,N,[...C,A],P>|a<R,N,[A],Q>:N extends Q["length"]?Q:[N,Q]extends[0,[[]]]?T:never;type b<D,N,M=[]>=N extends M["length"]?D:D extends[...infer D,{}]?b<D,N,[...M,0]>:never;type c<C>=C extends(infer C)[]?0 extends M<C>?0:1:0;type M<D>=D extends[infer C,...infer I,infer M]?1 extends c<a<b<I,M>,C>>?1:0:0
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

````
// Returns all the ways an array can be chunked into Count subarrays
type Chunkify<Unchunked, Count, CurChunk=[], PrevChunks=[], AllChunks=[...PrevChunks,CurChunk]> =
  // Get the first element of Unchunked
  Unchunked extends [infer El, ...infer Rest] 
    // Return a union of:
    ?
      // Continue this chunk
      | Chunkify<Rest, Count, [...CurChunk, El], PrevChunks>
      // Start a new chunk
      | Chunkify<Rest, Count, [El], AllChunks>
    // Unchunked is empty.
    // If AllChunks.length == Count,
    : Count extends AllChunks["length"]
      // Return AllChunks
      ? AllChunks
      // Otherwise, if Count == 0 and AllChunks == [[]],
      : [Count, AllChunks] extends [0, [[]]]
          // Return []
        ? Unchunked
        // Invalid chunking
        : never

type RemoveMetadata<
  Data,
  MetadataCount,
  RemovedCount=[]
> =
  // If RemovedCount == MetadataCount,
  MetadataCount extends RemovedCount["length"]
    // Return Data
    ? Data
    // Otherwise, pop the last element off of Data
    : Data extends [...infer Initial, {}]
      // Recurse, incrementing RemovedCount
      ? RemoveMetadata<Initial, MetadataCount, [...RemovedCount, 0]>
      // Data is empty, but we still need to strip more metadata; return never
      : never

type ValidateLicenses<Chunkifications> =
  // Map over Chunkifications, extracting the chunks as a union
  Chunkifications extends (infer Chunks)[]
    // Return 0 if any of Chunks are invalid licenses
    ? 0 extends ValidateLicense<Chunks> ? 0 : 1
    // Invalid
    : 0

type ValidateLicense<Data> =
  Data extends [infer ChildCount, ...infer InnerData, infer MetadataCount]
    // Return 1 if any of the ways to chunk RemoveMetadata<InnerData, MetadataCount> into ChildCount chunks are valid lists of licenses
    ? 1 extends ValidateLicenses<Chunkify<RemoveMetadata<InnerData, MetadataCount>, ChildCount>> ? 1 : 0
    // Invalid
    : 0

type T0 = ValidateLicense<[0, 0]>
//   ^?
type T1 = ValidateLicense<[1, 0, 0, 0]>
//   ^?
type T2 = ValidateLicense<[0, 99, 99, 99, 3]>
//   ^?
type T3 = ValidateLicense<[2, 0, 10, 11, 12, 3, 1, 0, 99, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]>
//   ^?
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 156 bytes

```rust
fn f(a:&[usize])->bool{let l=a.len();l>1&&((a[0]<1&&a[l-1]==l-2)||a[0]>0&&(2..l).any(|i|f(&a[1..i])&&f(&{let mut z=a[i..].to_vec();z.insert(0,a[0]-1);z})))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLdboMgFL7vU5z2wsCCBOxV29k9iCENWzAhodgpblnVZ@@O2nZdMzsi@HG@nwA5ZV2FU@5hr60nFJoe50Svo6yu7NEoGm9fi8I1zgRwqebOoGzjtjKKCNGZUM@IdOZiqdLUxQlt2766FcgnnDvKtf8irW1zgjLJuVU0inAzJO7rAMdUZ5ZzxUOx@zBvmH7k1lemDESwPiuWWOoopd0JcORFCcT6Qx0YaF99mpKC9RBlMzgPgjHzTDAQikEoa0PZHSeRG78pBXKr1c9cTumSIUb2E0Mlbpf4G4q9D1EyrPKCJ5OwnmtX/XGUaQZDJ0n5iBS3DzDpF@OJcZ1ULcf7X@JuwX/W5Lf8Ht/5FDRX/6G0Pjg/J4tm/dItGAztQDdXga76/tmZ9znBVhtZBk/ndhl13aw7fQM)

Making use of @G B's approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>101</s> 93 bytes

This uses [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/)'s observation.

```
h(x:y)|x>0=or[h$take n y|n<-[0..l y],h$x-1:drop n y]
h y@(0:_)=last y==l y-2
h _=1<0
l=length
```

-8 bytes thanks to alephalpha

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##XU1BCoMwELz3FXvwoKCSxJNiSv8RggQqTTFGUQ8G/LvdGMS2kM3O7MzOajV3rTH7ruO1csm23gkfJqGjRXUtWHCbrTNB8tyAk6mO1oxWz2kYvSRvGtwjJlWTcKPmBRznaMsYzhtOa3Iz3LT2tei9V28LHMbpbReIezWCBiFICkSmgmILDwm2sryqwBE7ROoLrRRpge0Yegsidvz0xH7JR4U4Gk7QwK5LISGkMeRFOHNavsFlYr/CP5Yy2T8)

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU1BCoMwELz3FXvwoKCSxJNiSv8RggQqTTFGUQ8G/LvdGMS2kM3O7MzOajV3rTH7ruO1csm23gkfJqGjRXUtWHCbrTNB8tyAk6mO1oxWz2kYvSRvGtwjJlWTcKPmBRznaMsYzhtOa3Iz3LT2tei9V28LHMbpbReIezWCBiFICkSmgmILDwm2sryqwBE7ROoLrRRpge0Yegsidvz0xH7JR4U4Gk7QwK5LISGkMeRFOHNavsFlYr/CP5Yy2T8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 62 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @att.

```
_f=1<0
f[0,x___,l_]:=l==Tr[1^{x}]
f[a_,x__/;f@x,y__]:=f[a-1,y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU1BCsMgELznFUKgJ0Ncc0pbi0/oobdgJZRKA0kPIYcE8e12VaRpwdXZmXFm6pfXc@qX4dF7r42AMytMx@iqtaajVkcxCnGbO7jb1SmUeh20@mTkSjcdDMhVQDflr/PwXrqSVBdiiJSkVAdSy8JaRglztCAWEKQTVwRt@50mkjwaIAzaAdcGn0gGEyIeb8g4fUuBORZyHWRm35vSUjKPTJNKs20P9jb@K/1j5/wH)

A port of [@G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/9288).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>44</s> 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"ćUX_iRćsgQë.œ2ùεεNiX<š}}}εε®.V}0ìP}à"©.V
```

Port of [*@GB*'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239887/52210).

Results in `1` for truthy and `0`/`""` for falsey (only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6Uh7aER8ZtCR9uL0wMOr9Y5ONjq889zWc1v9MiNsji6sra0FcQ6t0wurNTi8JqD28AKlQyv1wv7/jzbUMQBCw9j/urp5@bo5iVWVAA) or [verify (almost) all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/pSPtoRHxmUFH2ovTAw@v1js62ejwznNbz231y4ywObqwtrYWxDm0Ti@s1uDwmoDawwuUDq3UC/uv8z862kDHIFZHIdpQx0AHyjTQsbSEImMI3xCIDHUMjSB8kFKgnKGOkY4hiA9WA1UIkTeE8ODmwZkQWwxhTKCBOkYgDtAkiAwyDZIwBnMMkEiIntj/urp5@bo5iVWVAA) (the largest truthy test case times out because of `.œ`).

**Explanation:**

```python
"..."          # Push the string below
     ©         # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
      .V       # Execute it as 05AB1E code
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
ć              # Head extracted; pop and push remainder-list and first item separately
 U             # Pop and store this first item in variable `X`
X_i            # If `X` is 0:
   R           #  Reverse the remainder-list
    ć          #  Extract head again (or extract tail actually)
     s         #  Swap so the remainder-list is at the top
      g        #  Pop and push the length of this remainder-list
       Q       #  Check if it's equal to the extracted tail
  ë            # Else:
   .œ          #  Get all possible partitions of the remainder-list
     2ù        #  And only keep those consisting of two partition-parts
       ε       #  Map over each partition:
        ε      #   Inner map over both partition-parts:
         Ni    #    If it's the second part:
           X<  #     Push `X` and decrease it by 1
             š #     Prepend it in front of the partition-part
          }    #    Close the if-statement
        }      #   Close the inner map
       }       #  Close the outer map
        ε      #  Map over the partitions again:
         ε     #   Inner map over both partition-parts again:
          ®    #    Push string `®`
           .V  #    And execute it as 05AB1E code as recursive call
         }     #   After the inner map:
          0ì   #   Prepend a 0 in front of each result
            P  #   Get the product of this result to check if all were truthy
        }      #  After the outer map:
         à     #  Get the maximum to check if any were truthy
```

Some notes:

- 05AB1E lacks any recursive methods, but with `"..."©.V` and `®.V` we can mimic this behavior.
- You may be wondering why we first close the maps and then do the exact same maps again at `}}εε`? We do this to first create the correct partitions, before we do the recursive calls, otherwise variable `X` will be incorrectly overwritten by the inner recursive call. In *@GB*'s Ruby answer, the variables `a` and `b` are within scope of the function, whereas in my full program, the `X` (which is basically variable `a`) would be overwritten in the inner calls.
- `ć` results in an empty string if the list is empty, which is why we use the `0ì` before the `P` to convert all empty strings to `0`, while keeping all other integers the same.